# Porting access to pixels from PixelPacket in API C++ of ImageMagick 7

Tags: c++, qt, api, imagemagick

I try porting code with using ImageMagick-7.0.0-Q16-HDRI.

This code work with ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16:

```
QString ImageMagick::fromQImage(const QImage &qimage){
    if (!qimage.size().isValid()) return "ImageMagick::fromQImage - Empty Qimage";
    image = Magick::Image(Magick::Geometry(qimage.width(), qimage.height()), Magick::ColorRGB(0.5, 0.2, 0.3));
    double scale = 1 / 255.0;
    image.modifyImage();
    Magick::PixelPacket *pixels;
    Magick::ColorRGB mgc;
    for (int y = 0; y < qimage.height(); y++) {
        pixels = image.setPixels(0, y, image.columns(), 1);
        for (int x = 0; x < qimage.width(); x++) {
            QColor pix = qimage.pixel(x, y);
            // *pixels++ = Magick::ColorRGB(256 * pix.red(), 256 * pix.green(), 256 * pix.blue());
            mgc.red(scale *pix.red());
            mgc.green(scale *pix.green());
            mgc.blue(scale *pix.blue());
            // *pixels++ = Magick::ColorRGB(scale *pix.red(), scale * pix.green(), scale * pix.blue());
            pixels[x] = mgc;
        }
        image.syncPixels();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now I must use by http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php instead `PixelPacket`:

```
MagickCore::Quantum *pixels;
```

Where in some case:

- pixels[0]- red channel of pixel
- pixels[1]- green channel of pixel
- pixels[2]- blue channel of pixel

How will work with SetPixelRed()... instead of `pixels[x] = mgc;`

```
MagickCore::SetPixelRed((MagickCore::Image*)&image,scale*pix.red(),pixels+x*3);
MagickCore::SetPixelGreen((MagickCore::Image*)&image,scale*pix.green(),pixels+x*3);
MagickCore::SetPixelBlue((MagickCore::Image*)&image,scale*pix.blue(),pixels+x*3);
```

But it right now is?

Found next solution:

```
size_t imageQuantum = MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH;
size_t toFloatQuantum=(pow(2,imageQuantum)-1);
size_t imageChanells=image.channels();
```

...

```
pixels[x*imageChanells]=mgc.red()*toFloatQuantum;
pixels[x*imageChanells+1]=mgc.green()*toFloatQuantum;
pixels[x*imageChanells+2]=mgc.blue()*toFloatQuantum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really good question, but I think you're attacking this problem from the wrong angle.

If `Quantum` is returned from `Magick::Pixels.get` then just apply `QColor`  directly to the value, and `sync`

```cpp
Magick::Image img(Magick::Geometry(2,2), Magick::Color("white"));
img.modifyImage();
Magick::Pixels view(img);
Magick::Quantum * pixels = view.get(0, 0, 2, 2);
int x,y;
for (y= 0; y < 2 ; y++ ) {
    for (x = 0 ; x < 2 ; x++ ) {
        // As we starting the pixels as white, we can
        // leverage multiplication assignment (*=) operator.
        *pixels++ *= pix.red()  / 255.0; // Red
        *pixels++ *= pix.green()/ 255.0; // Green
        *pixels++ *= pix.blue() / 255.0; // Blue
    }
}
view.sync()
```

No need to invoke any additional class(es) from `MagickCore`

Comment: `Magick::PixelPacket  *pixels;` // error C2038 PixelPacket : is not member of 'Magick'

`view.get(...` - return array of Quantums

`Magick::Pixels Quantum *get(const ::ssize_t x_,const ::ssize_t y_,
      const size_t columns_,const size_t rows_);`

Comment: Argh, I'm an idiot for not running my own code. I'll updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Can be Quantum value more Q16 65535 ?
I have pixel values after filter AdaptiveSharp (Radius 4, sigma 1) : `RGBpixel   68556.8 75715.5 69944.4`

Comment: @lexxai Can't say. Better jump over to [official forums](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/index.php). This might be handled in application, or undefined behavior.